# How do I find a specific word (string) from a users input in lua

Tags: lua

I have been trying now for some time to see if any input given by the user contains a specific word,  for example ("Thank you", "Thanks", "thanks" ) etc

Im not sure though how to be able to find if the users input contains a specific string word, I am also not very good at lua coding, eep eep!

Answer (score 0):

Lua Reference Manual to the rescue!

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.find

> **string.find (s, pattern [, init [, plain]])** Looks for the first match of pattern (see §6.4.1) in the string s. If it finds a match,
> then find returns the indices of s where this occurrence starts and
> ends; otherwise, it returns fail. A third, optional numeric argument
> init specifies where to start the search; its default value is 1 and
> can be negative. A value of true as a fourth, optional argument plain
> turns off the pattern matching facilities, so the function does a
> plain "find substring" operation, with no characters in pattern being
> considered magic.
>
> If the pattern has captures, then in a successful match the captured
> values are also returned, after the two indices.

or

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match

> **string.match (s, pattern [, init])** Looks for the first match of the pattern (see §6.4.1) in the string s. If it finds one, then match
> returns the captures from the pattern; otherwise it returns fail. If
> pattern specifies no captures, then the whole match is returned. A
> third, optional numeric argument init specifies where to start the
> search; its default value is 1 and can be negative.

Example:

```
local input = "love is in the air"
print(input:find("air"))
print(input:match("air"))
```

`input:find("air")` is bascially short for `input:match("()ai()r")`

Edit:
In case you don't know how to get user input:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.read

Comment: I didnt want to know how to find a certain word in a string variable, I wanted to find what the client has written for input to the computer/code and see if the clients input contains a specific word.

Comment: sorry but I cannot make any sense of your comment. you asked how to find a specific word in the user input. I showed you how to find the word `air` as an example. any text in Lua comes as a string. so does your client's input. so finding something in the users input is done in the exact same way. if you don't know how to get user input then you should probably have mentioned that in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpfull because it can match more than one time in one run and return how often it matches.
So deciding on how much occurencies of the pattern `([tT]han%g+)` matching is possible.
The magic string function used for this is: `gsub()`
Example typed in Lua Konsole...

```
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
texts = setmetatable({}, {__call = function(self) if #self > 0 then return self[#self]:gsub('([tT]han%g+)','*%1*') end end, __index = {insert = table.insert}})
> texts:insert([[Hello ...                                                                                

My name is Thomas T. Thank
I would like to thank you...
Thanks in advance]])
> texts()
Hello ...

My name is Thomas T. *Thank*
I would like to *thank* you...
*Thanks* in advance 3
> do local txt, occ = texts() if occ > 0 then io.write(occ,' occurencies in...\n', txt, '\n...found.\n') end end
3 occurencies in...
Hello ...

My name is Thomas T. *Thank*
I would like to *thank* you...
*Thanks* in advance
...found.
```

...also `gsub()` is a fine translator or find and replace function.